# What is the difference between Ostracodermi and Placodermi

Tags: terminology, taxonomy, etymology

I looked the word origin and found Placodermi is PLATE SKINNED while Ostracodermi is Shell Skinned.
Can someone please explain the difference between being *Plate* skinned and *Shell* skinned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in reference to the prehistoric groups of fish of the respective classifications, ostracoderms would have had a bony head much like a shell, and placoderms had articulated plates covering the head/thoracic area. The differences are relatively straightforward, see the wikipedia pages for each:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostracoderm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placodermi